# Creating a docker image to scaffold django projects

Tags: django, docker, django-admin

I'm build a docker image that can scaffold out a docker project using this 
**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD ["pip","install Django"]

CMD ["django-admin", "startproject hello_world_django"]
```

I build the image using:

```
docker build django-scaffold .
```

and run it using

```
docker run django-scaffold
```

**Error message**:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"django-admin\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

When I run this docker image, I am informed that the command `django-admin` is not available.

How can I add `django-admin` to the path within the container?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as below for getting started with Docker -

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip3 install django==2.1.4 && \
    django-admin startproject hello_world_django

CMD [ "python3", "./hello_world_django/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

PS - Using multiple CMD's in single Dockerfile will override in turn and only the last CMD in Dockerfile will be executed. Also, anything you add in CMD has to be a foreground process.

Comment: I can run the command now but I get the message:
  No Django settings specified. Unknown command: 'startproject hello_world_django' Type 'django-admin help' for usage.

Comment: I am using this doc to setup django-admin startproject 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname

Comment: You can add something like `--settings=production_settings` wherever required.